# Offline github app for android

Tags: android, github

I want to write documentation with android while I am traveling.

The network connection is slow and interrupted often.

Is there an android app where I can commit locally and commits get pushed later if the connection is stable?

There are several apps which enable you to browse github, but you can't edit files with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Pocket Git](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.pocketgit):

> Pocket Git is a powerful standalone Git client for Android with the following features:
>
> ★ Simple interface. ★ Clone repositories. ★ Support HTTP and SSH
>   protocols. ★ Passwords and private keys (with passphrase). ★
>   Automatically capture Github and Bitbucket links. ★ Checkout local and
>   remote branches, individual commits and tags. ★ Stage, unstage and
>   commit. ★ Merge, create and delete branches. ★ Create and delete tags.
>   ★ Create files and folders. ★ Edit files in a external editor (e.g.
>   DroidEdit). ★ Revert changes to single files or complete working tree.
>   ★ Push, pull and fetch from remotes. ★ Projects with more than one
>   remote. ★ Graphical log. ★ View differences before commiting. ★ View
>   differences for each commit. ★ View differences, for any file, between
>   current working tree and HEAD.

I use it with the editor of the same author (DroidEdit)

It costs only few Euros.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it up to now, but [MGit](http://github.com/maks/MGit) looks alive:

> MGit is a Git client Android App.
>
> ```
> Create local repositories
> Clone remote repositories
> Pull from origin
> Delete local repositories
> Browse files
> Browse commit messages (short)
> Checkout branches and tags
> HTTP/HTTPS/SSH are supported (including SSH with private key passphrase)
> Username/Password authentication is supported
> Search local repositories
> Private key management
> Manually choose code language
> git diff between commits
> Import existing repositories (that is, you can copy a repository from computer and import to MGit)
> Checkout remote branches
> Merge branches
> Push merged content
> Edit file (built-in editor or external app that can edit the given file type)
> Commit and push changed files
> Committer information
> Prompt for password
> Option to save username/password
> git status
> Cancel when cloning
> Add modified file to stage
> View state of staged files (aka index)
> git rebase
> git cherrypick
> git checkout <file> (reset changes of a file)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, [FastHub](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/FastHub) does. FastHub was created in 2017. The idea of a FastHub creator is due to the fact that most of the few GitHub client apps are either don't have many features, look good, or buggy.

The development is also active by creators and contributors from time to time make FastHub better. Now FastHub almost has many features as on the GitHub website.

FastHub provides what you need when you use the GitHub service on your phone. The features in FastHub are great. These are the main features that are useful:

**Themes Mode**

FastHub has several themes. That is Light theme, Dark theme, Amoled theme, and Dark blue theme.

**Material Design UI**

All pages in FastHub include Feeds, Profile page, Issues, and PR page, Trending, Gist has a great looking material design.

**Trending**

You can also choose a specific programming language and view trending daily/weekly/monthly.

**Offline Mode**

This is really helpful when you have connection problems and you can still see some repos and files you have visited.

**Notification**

The push notification works well, you can set the sync interval between 1 minute/5 minutes/10 minutes/30 minutes/1 hour/2 hours/3 hours.

**Search Users/Orgs, Repos, Issues/PRs & Code**

The search results have been categorized and it's easy to switch.

The features that are common and important in Repository, Issues, Pull Request, Profile, Gist, etc on the GitHub website are almost available in FastHub. [**See more features**](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/FastHub#features).

**Download**

Source Code on [GitHub](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/FastHub) • Get it on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fastaccess.github) •

Comment: Can I edit markdown files while I am offline with FastHub?

Comment: Yes, It supports offline mode.